# live pose estimation (6DoF) with one camera opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to estimate the pose (6DoF) of a paper in world coordinate with opencv.
The camera is fixed and the paper is moved. 
Three dots of diffrent colors are painted on the paper as markers. 
Is it possible to do it lively with only one camera?
I have the intrinsic matrix and the distortion parameters.
I read somewhere that it is only possible with a 3d model of the object.
Are those three points enough information or is there anything still missing?
And how should I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want the paper to flip over?  are you **sure** you mean 6dof?  so to begin with you'd need markers on the other side as well.  is the paper perfectly stiff (like a sheet of metal) or does it bend and flop like paper?

Comment: It's important that the paper is attached to something rigid, because an important part of the algorithm you'd use requires knowing the distance between the dots in the "model," which in your case is just the paper.

Comment: yes I mean 6 dof, but the rotations around x and y axis should be limitted to around 15 degrees. And the paper will be attached to something rigid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it possible to do pose estimation with one camera, but you need at least **four points**. If you only have three, there are four possible orientations for the triangle. [Depending on how mathematically inclined you are, you can go through the work [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MARBLE/high/pia/solving.htm)]. Note that the distances between the colored points count as your "model" for the paper.

Proceeding from there, you'll be likely to find code that will work for you if you search for "pose estimation", along with whatever libraries / tools / languages you're planning to use. I recommend trying an example, even if it doesn't involve your paper and colored dots, before jumping in and writing code.

Comment: why are you saying that I need at least five points? the work from your link says you need four points if they are coplanar.

Comment: My bad, I read it wrong. Then, you only need four. Edits have been made.